# TYPO3 - MySQL to mm Query Syntax

Tags: typo3

I have an working MySQL Query now i need it to convert to Typo3 Syntax

```
SELECT 
  tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local, 
  fe_users.* 
FROM fe_users
   JOIN tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm
    ON tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign =  fe_users.uid
WHERE tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local = 101
```

TYPO3

```
        $res0 = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query(
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local,fe_users.*',
            'fe_users',
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm',
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign = fe_users.uid',
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local = 101',
            '',
            '',
            ''
        );
```

the result is empty...anybody knows how this work with typo3?

Debug brings this: $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debug_lastBuiltQuery;

```
SELECT tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local,fe_users.* 
    FROM fe_users,tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm,tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign = fe_users.uid 
    WHERE fe_users.uid=tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local 
    AND tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign = fe_users.uid.uid=tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local = 101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `exec_SELECT_mm_query` the 4th parameter is the foreign key table name, not the reference. You need instead of:

```
tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign = fe_users.uid
```

only:

```
fe_users
```

See more details in [TYPO3 api : exec_SELECT_mm_query](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html#a7e954e50312403831a74d3013ef96f0b).

I think, you can try the following:

```
$res0 = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query(
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local,fe_users.*',
            'tt_news',
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm',
            'fe_users',
            'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local = 101',
            '',
            '',
            ''
        );
```

Or you can use exactly the SQL what you have with the following little trick, because [exe_SELECTquery](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_dbal_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html#a3e108e17834da69d638f3d9301f06628) only concats your string to `SELECT..., FROM...` (and so on...) parts. So because of this, you can use a `JOIN` in `FROM` part.

```
$res0 = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local,fe_users.*',
'fe_users
   JOIN tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm
    ON tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_foreign =  fe_users.uid',
 'tt_news_tx_extendnews_subscriber_mm.uid_local = 101',
 '',
 '',
 '');
```